# wxWidgets listctrl multiselect GetNextItem Bug?

Tags: list, wxwidgets

I use wxWidgets 2.9.5 on a Windows 7 machine.

When I select more then one element in my wxlistctrl using shift, GetNextItem() only returns the index of the first element selected.

Even the example from the manual: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_ctrl.html#ad8372c4619ad5ea55ad16889caa32e78

which I attached doesn't work; Hence it returns the index of the first element selected when the GetNextItem() is called at first, but when it is called the second time it returns -1.

```
long item = -1;

for ( ;; )
{
item = listctrl->GetNextItem(item,wxLIST_NEXT_ALL,wxLIST_STATE_SELECTED);
if ( item == -1 )
break;
// this item is selected - do whatever is needed with it
wxLogMessage("Item %ld is selected.", item);
}
```

Does anyone has had to workaround the same problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Just for clarity: the code shown in this question does work and didn't correspond to the code that was tested (and contained a bug).

Answer (score 0):

Almost exactly the same code (see `MyFrame::OnShowSelInfo()`) does work in the listctrl sample included in wxWidgets, so I really don't know why it doesn't work for you. Can you try to reproduce the problem in the sample?

Comment: I had a look at the sample before but at least in my one i can't even mark several items by holding the shift key

Comment: OK, i figured it out... what a silly mistake, I deleted an item at the end of the loop so the length of the list changed and that messed everything up

Comment: The solution was to change the first parameter of GetNextItem to -1 instead of 'item'